# [Charts JS]: Изменение данных в 'tooltip'

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!)
Ситуация такая: приходит значение (...: 1.093.731), которое впоследствии я конвертирую в нужный мне размер. Но в 'tooltip' Отображается пришедшее значение (...: 1.093.731), возможно ли как-то его убрать из отображения в 'tooltip'?
P.S. Значение должно быть таким для корректного отображения, но видно его быть не должно.

Заранее спасибо[image: Tooltip]

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
tooltip: {
                        callbacks: {
                            label: (item) => {
                                Смотрим что выводит консоль и меняем нужные нам поля console.log(item);
                                return;
                            },
                        },
                    },
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]